# How to replace a line in a file with a string in Python, whose length is less than the line to be replaced?

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a line in a file, with a string whose length differs based on the input.
If the length of string is equal to or greater than the line to be replaced,
then the file is overwritten correctly. Whereas, if the string is shorter than the line to be replaced,
then after replacing, part of the line will be appended at the end.

The code snippet used for writing to the file is given below.

```
replace_value = status
lines = []
filename = open(os.path.join(dst_path, asilSafety_path),'r+')
for line in filename.readlines():
    line.strip('\n')
    if line.startswith('export SAFETY_SRV_MODE'):
        bits = line.split('=')
        config, value = bits
        src = config + '=' + value.strip('\n')
        target = config + '= ' + replace_value
        break
filename.seek(0)
for line in filename.readlines():
    line = line.replace(src,target)
    lines.append(line)
filename.seek(0)
for line in lines:
    filename.write(line)
filename.close()
```

I am passing the file path and the string to be written as arguments to the function i.e., safety_configuration(dst_path, status). The variable 'replace_value' has the string to be replaced with.

Can someone please tell me, wat am i doing wrong? Or is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: can you show the how your file look like expected output will be easy to solve

Comment: I would also consider reading the entire file and using `re.sub` instead if the file is not huge. It will make your code much shorter and cleaner.

Comment: I don't think that `src` is sure to match your line. Why not write `src=line.strip()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
import fileinput
import sys
count = 0
replace_value = status
for line in fileinput.input(["a.txt"], inplace=True, backup='.bak'):

    if line.startswith('export SAFETY_SRV_MODE'):
        bits = line.split('=')
        config, value = bits
        src = config + '=' + value.strip('\n')
        target = config + '= ' + replace_value+"\n"
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(src,target))

    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

You can use file input for this instead of moving up and down the file you can change it at the time when you found it

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looping over the lines in the file once, and if they don't match what you want to replace, simply append them to `lines`.

If they do, modify that line before appending it to `lines`. The simply re-write them out to the file.

```
replace_value = status
lines = []

with open(os.path.join(dst_path, asilSafety_path)) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('export SAFETY_SRV_MODE'):
            config, value = line.split('=')
            lines.append(config + '= ' + replace_value + '\n')
        else:
            lines.append(line)

with open(os.path.join(dst_path, asilSafety_path), 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct provide you have enough memory to load whole file. You simply forgot to `truncate` the file object, and that's the reason why you see garbage at the end.

The last part of your script should be :

```
filename.seek(0)
for line in lines:
    filename.write(line)
filename.truncate()
filename.close()
```

You can also truncate immediately after the `seek`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Now there is no more garbage getting appended at the EOF.